# wso2 AM 1.8 ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist when importing swagger definition

Tags: swagger, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to register a rest api published with swagger into the wso2 Api Manager 1.8.
In the wso2 publisher I do "Import swagger definition"
It shows me all the apis under the "Resources", but if I do "save" I get the exception below in the log.
How can I fix it?

THANKS
Alberto

My env is:

Linux hqldvwsos1 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.0.el6_6-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)

TID: [0] [AM] [2015-02-10 10:18:14,592] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider} -  Error while retrieving Swagger Definition for SDRESTAPI-1.1.1 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/SDRESTAPI-1.1.1-admin/1.2/default/budget-codes
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:532)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getGhostResourceFromCache(CacheBackedRegistry.java:194)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:167)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:620)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:603)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:600)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.getSwagger12Definition(APIProviderImpl.java:2431)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.getSwagger12Definition(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:33)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getSwagger12Resource(APIProviderHostObject.java:755)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_4(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:75)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_32(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:104)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_2(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:209)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:18)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-02-10 10:18:14,597] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag} -  org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while retrieving Swagger Definition for SDRESTAPI-1.1.1 {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag}

----- UPdate n1 ----

I found some inconsistency in the swagger definition.

For example I had

```
apis:
  - path: /api/budget-codes
    description: Budget Codes
    file:
      apiVersion: "1.0"
      swaggerVersion: "1.2"
      basePath: /fsd
      resourcePath: /api/budget
```

Now I changed the first "budget-codes" into "budget" and I'm not getting the exception I documented. I can save it, but if I go to the implementation step or if I save and re-read the Design step, I get

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-02-10 11:15:19,655] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag} -  java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [B {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag}
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alberto,

Did you edit your swagger definition after importing? If you made changes make sure authorization header is in the following format.

```
authorizations: 
     oauth2: 
        type: oauth2 
        scopes: []
```

Comment: I added the autorization header after the apis section and before the info section, but I'm still getting the same exception: any idea? THANKS

Comment: Can you provide your swagger definition Alberto?

Comment: Please note that resourcePath can't have values such as /api/budget, should be /budget. The path attribute inside an api can have value as  /api/budget.

Comment: you can find the swagger definition here:
https://gist.github.com/alagna/ba50ec3c25a4d0c0168a

Comment: Alberto, did you make an api before with same content before and deleted it from management console? This error says that it can't find the api in path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/SDRESTAPI-1.1.1-admin/1.2/default/budget-codes.   This usually happens when you try to delete an API from the management console. Please refer this link and follow it to fix your issue. http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-fix-issue-in-subscription-page.html

Comment: I did a fresh installation of AM.

I did "edit swagger definition" with the https://gist.github.com/alagna/d4c22d3e18c0015fd588, in which I was following the suggestion above "Please note that resourcePath can't have values such as ...."

I saved the swagger definition and I still get
ERROR - UserAwareAPIProvider Error while retrieving Swagger Definition for ORGSupportDataRESTAPI-1.1.1
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/ORGSupportDataRESTAPI-1.1.1-admin/1.2/budget